# Problem with HTTP Connections

Tags: c#, http, connection, persistence

I've a big problem (sorry for my poor english).
I attach directly my code:

```
public bool isServerOnline()
{
        Boolean ret = false;

        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(VPMacro.MacroUploader.SERVER_URL);
            req.Method = "HEAD";
            req.KeepAlive = false;
            HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
            if (resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                // HTTP = 200 - Internet connection available, server online
                ret = true;
            }
            resp.Close();
            return ret;

        }
        catch (WebException we)
        {
            // Exception - connection not available
            Log.e("InternetUtils - isServerOnline - " + we.Status);
            return false;
        }
}
```

This function is invoked by a lot of thread and send HEAD requests to a Tomcat Server.
So, this method open a connection for each request that I perform and within 10 minutes I've 100 connection active.

How I resolve this problem?

Comment: How are you measuring the 100 connections live?  And also, why is that a problem?

Comment: I've opened Tomcat Manager and I see session number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomcat Manager shows sessions, not active TCP connections.  Each request might start a new session, but an active session does not necessarily indicate an active TCP connection.

Comment: If that's the case could you accept this as an answer please :)

Comment: Sure. I set this answer as right. But, can you tell me how can I solve sessions problem?

Comment: @Cecco: the "problem" is on the server, not the client. Apparently Tomcat is keeping the session active for some period of time. There should be a configuration option that tells it how long to keep sessions alive. You might not want to change that, though.

Comment: Ok, I open a new question so this remains clean. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

2 things you could do to properly manage a connection:

first:

initialize

```
HttpWebResponse resp;
```

before the try statement.

Then close in a finally statement

```
finally
{ 
    if (resp != null) 
    {
        resp.Close();
    }
}
```

second:

Try managing your connections with the "using()" clause

```
using(var a = new connection())
{
    //Your code
}
```